# Simple CSS3 keyframe animation doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I have created one simple CSS3 keyframe animation that switches bg image of an element.
It is working perfectly, but my trusty Firefox has failed me. I was using prefix free at first, then I thought that it may be the problem, after that I wrote all prefixes by hand, still nothing in Firefox.

You can see the example at: http://madebym.me/test/nimbus/index.html

Also, here is the relevant code, the truck should switch lights on and off.

```
-webkit-animation: switch-truck-lights 1s linear infinite normal;
-moz-animation: switch-truck-lights 1s linear infinite normal;
-ms-animation: switch-truck-lights 1s linear infinite normal;
-o-animation: switch-truck-lights 1s linear infinite normal;
animation: switch-truck-lights 1s linear infinite normal;
}

@keyframes "switch-truck-lights" {
from {
    background-image: url(../images/truck-off.png);
}

to {
    background-image: url(../images/truck-on.png);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes switch-truck-lights {
    from {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-off.png);
    }

    to {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-on.png);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes "switch-truck-lights" {
    from {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-off.png);
    }

    to {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-on.png);
    };
}

@-ms-keyframes "switch-truck-lights" {
    from {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-off.png);
    }

    to {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-on.png);
    };
}

@-o-keyframes "switch-truck-lights" {
    from {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-off.png);
    }

    to {
        background-image: url(../images/truck-on.png);
    };
}
```

Comment: Also, I now see that it fails in IE10 and Safari on Windows. I could create a sprite, and then animate bg position, but I am really curious why this does work in Chrome and not in the other browsers. It vouldn't be any simpler.

Comment: The simple thing is update your Firefox browser. Actually your site is working perfectly fine in Firefox 22.0 same as in chrome.

Comment: working in firefox 22 and IE10 as well

Comment: Sorry, guys, didn't update the question earlier. It works, because I am animating bg position of sprite image. It seems that background-image is not a valid CSS transition/animation property. Only Chrome, for some reason can animate bg position.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that background-position is not an [valid transition/animation property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).
 For some reason it works in Chrome, but the only other solution is to fade-in-out absolutely positioned images, or to animate background position of image sprite.

Which is exatly what I had done.